# Pandas function Unstack()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-series

I am working on preparing a time series data frame, and I am trying to set the index. Below is an example:

```
a = {'a': ['ce', 'ce', 'ce', 'ce', 'ce', 'ce'], 'b' : ['SAM', 'SAM', 'SAM', 'WHR', 'SAM', 'WHR'],
     'c': ['11-22-2015', '11-23-2015', '11-24-2015', '11-25-2015', '11-26-2015', '11-27-2015'],
     'd' : ['ICU', 'ICU', 'ICU', 'MED', 'MED', 'SUR'], 'e' : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Result is:

```
df
```

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ce | SAM | 11-22-2015 | ICU | 1 |
| ce | SAM | 11-23-2015 | ICU | 2 |
| ce | SAM | 11-24-2015 | ICU | 4 |
| ce | WHR | 11-25-2015 | MED | 6 |
| ce | SAM | 11-26-2015 | MED | 5 |
| ce | WHR | 11-27-2015 | SUR | 3 |

I am trying to set the index for that data frame using the code below:

```
df_unstacked = df.set_index(['d', 'c', 'b']).unstack(['b', 'd'])
```

Now I get this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Why is that, and How I can fix?

Comment: this doesn't reproduce the error

Comment: @mozway Would you please explain more?

Comment: I ran your code: I have an unstacked dataframe, no error

Comment: @mozway, Great, thanks for your feedback. Any ideas on how to make it works on my Jupiter notebook?

Comment: Do you have an up to date pandas?

Comment: @mozway Yes, I just updated all libraries and now I have pandas 1.4.3 and it is still giving same error